# Empty Desktop Folder?

Tags: command-prompt

Hi I'm relatively new to coding, and I'm having trouble with finding the desktop which has my desktop files in it - I'm in the correct drive with the directory users(me)\desktop and there's no files in here even though when I searched for it in file explorer it had the desktop icon and seemed legit as my desktop.  How can I open the "desktop" in which I can explore and open my desktop files?

Thanks.

Comment: I feel it is wrong website to ask such a question

Comment: Isn't this a website to ask questions for coding? I'm asking how to manage my file directory - a foundation in starting to do programming, finding and opening files you saved.